# Sharing authentication between two web applications

Tags: iis-7, forms-authentication, shared

I have a base web site (**Asp.net WebForms** application) running under ie.

```
http://localhost:90/
```

Then I created a new (this time **Asp.net MVC**) application and added it under

```
http://localhost:90/mvc/
```

but not just as a simple virtual folder, but as an **application folder** by defining a different **application pool** to run it, compared to the *parent* application.

Since browsers can't know that there are two different application basically on the same domain it would work like:

1. user accesses `http://localhost:90/`
2. parent app redirects the user to forms authentication screen
3. user successfully logs in
4. parent web adds an authentication cookie
5. user accesses `http://localhost:90/mvc`
6. browser attaches the same cookie from parent app

Is it possible that I authenticate the user based on this same cookie? I would configure my MVC application to login redirect to parent app to have a shared authentication screen. But I'd like to know who authenticated and work from that point on.

I've read something about sharing the same `system.web/machineKey` values to provide this kind of functionality, but I would like some real world examples.

I'm aware that these two applications will not be able to share Session state and that's not a problem, because I don't want them to. All I want is a kind of single login (SSO/SSS)

**Is this possible?** How?

### Important

I've read other questions/answers about this, but they are either asking about cross-domain/cross-server etc. This one is on the same IIS web site.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**I found it myself.**

This is the article on MSDN that talks exactly about this scenario. I decided to keep this question anyway for anyone that would be chasing the same information some time later.

[MSDN: Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

### In brief

You have to configure machine keys in `web.config` of both applications so they match hence they'll be able to decode data that the other party generated. And that's the whole trick. MSDN article explains this in great detail including how to generate those keys.

Comment: I did every thing my one app is on mvc 4.5 and other is on 3.5 webforms configured to run on local IIS but they are not sharing the cookies :(

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I think  one more configuration is missing  as both project run on localhost cookie will shared but in actual scenario domain name must be configured for sub domain SSO functionality.e.g for www.example.com,test.example.com,dev.example.com for all these domain name cookie configure for domain ".example.com" so this cookie shared by all sub domain.

Answer (score 7):

If in case anyone is still not able to share the keys use 
**`compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"`**

```xml
<machineKey validationKey="same key all over" 
            decryptionKey="same key all over" 
            validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
            compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"/>
```

Comment: Hi Syed, I tried but still not working - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506551/reading-cookie-value-using-url-rewrite-provider-module-unable-to-validate-at/34531147?noredirect=1#comment56945476_34531147

Comment: Works for me but wonder if there are disadvantages to going back to .NET 2 compatability

Comment: Framework20SP1 is probably best for testing does it work but I think it's recommended to choose newest working compatibility mode from: Framework20SP1 | Framework20SP2 | Framework45. More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.machinekeysection.compatibilitymode(v=vs.110).aspx