# return Redirect to url with HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, basic-authentication

From website 1 (my MVC app) is it possible to redirect to an url (website 2) and automatically authenticate it?

I've tried with `return Redirect("http://login:password@www.targetwebsite.com");`

However, this is not working in IE and in many other browsers/versions.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

**P.S.:** At this point I am also open to solution of the kind: return my own page(view) and do the "redirect" with authentication on the **client side using Javascript** (I just can't find a solution for that neither). Feel free to share a solution if you know.

Comment: It works this way, maybe you need to escape @ to \@ depending on programming language

Comment: @AtulGupta thanks for the feedback, but unfortunatly any way is working, IE10, Firefox25, etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, if both applications are managed by you [check this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035471/sharing-authentication-between-two-web-applications) otherwise it may and may not be possible.