# Share Windows-authentication between applications on the same domain

Tags: .net, iis, dynamics-crm-2011, windows-authentication

I have an issue similar to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035471/sharing-authentication-between-two-web-applications), but I use Windows authentication instead of Forms authentication.

First, the user logs in to a CRM application. Inside, I have an iframe with another application on the same domain. That application again prompts the user to log in. Both use Windows authentication.
The applications are running on two differnet sites in IIS and using seperate application pools.

How do I automatically sign the user in to the application in the iframe?

Comment: Check to see if all other authentication modes are disabled, except for windows authentication. Windows authentication providers should reflect what you have in place, if Kerberos is set up use Negotiate and remove other providers, else, add NTLM and remove other providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the website in IIS and double click on Authentication icon

[image]

Then make sure that only Windows Authentication is Enabled and all the rest is disabled.

[image]