# OWIN Authentication in subdomains

Tags: owin, rdlc, virtual-directory

For last 1 day, I'm trying to access a simple **RDLC** based project from my main project using virtual directories.

But this shows an error as,

[image: error]

Here, I don't want to mark `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />` as `false`. How can i overcome this issue?

[Sharing authentication between two web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035471/sharing-authentication-between-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please copy an error message to the question. Try to put as much useful information as possible into the question in case external sources become unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a seperate `owin:AppStartup` value for my child application, under appSettings as shown below:

`<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="SampleReport.Startup,SampleReport"/>` which made this application accessible under my parent application.